# How to split out and rename code files in git while preserving history?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, code-structure

I am new to git and now facing a git repo 'housekeeping' challenge after deciding to clean up the code structure. There are two dimensions to my challenge:

1. Need to rename suboptimally titled REPO, and some SUBFOLDERS and FILES to a clean python standard notation (from using dashes to shorter names with underscores etc.).
2. Split out test code into .py files saved in a dedicated \tests folder.

I discovered that doing the above code and file structure clean up in git is hard with preserving the change history. The other answers on the topic appear to cover a part of this effort. I attempted renaming files via git online but, while the history is formally kept, it only stores the bulk deletion act of a big chunk of test code that has been moved to \test folder. The newly created \tests\basic_test.py and \tests\advanced_test.py files are apparently treated as new by git i.e. have zero prior history of changes.

In short, **I need to split out the test code into new files stored in a new \tests subfolder and then rename the root code folder finishing up by renaming the repo.** Is this possible to be done without use of git command line? If not I guess it's my time to learn it and I appreciate the guidance to implementing exactly what I need above to jump in the water but not get bogged down in the git command line tutorials i.e. effect the change I need with minimum theory acquisition.

Thanks a lot for sharing the wisdom!

```html
- mt code structure 1.0

\money-tracker # local dir and git repo name    
  money_tracker_v01_9.4


- mt code structure 2.0

\money_tracker # app root_dir (local dir and git repo name)
  \mt # code_dir (shared code base named after main mod)
   mt.py

  \tests
   test_basic.py
   test_advanced.py

   \data_in (private, local)
    coa.csv
    trxn_data_x.csv

   \data_out (private, local)
    cf_report_x.txt

* each mt_dir may contain aux files (f.e. __init__.py, context.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum theoretical part that you must learn is this: Git doesn't *have* file history.  Git has commits, and the commits *are* the history.  Each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file.<sup>1</sup>

Git can, at any time, compare any two existing commits.  If there is a file named *F* in the old commit, and a file named *F* in the new commit, we generally assume that this is *the same file*.  But suppose that the old commit has a file named `old/path/to/name1.py` and the new commit has a file named `new/name/of/name2.py`.<sup>2</sup>  Then maybe those should be considered "the same file", even though they have different names.

If some commit renames some file, Git can try to *detect* that rename.  This rename detection depends on the files being similar enough in terms of content.  A 100% match on content guarantees that Git can find the rename pretty easily.  So when you have a commit that *just* renames the files, telling Git *tell me what changed in this one commit, and by the way, detect renames while you're doing that* <sup>3</sup> will make Git compare the "before" snapshot to the "after one", and it will find all the renames.

In order to show you a pretend "file history" with `git log --follow -- path`, Git simply looks at each *commit*.  Git starts at the end and works backwards (it always does this), comparing the before-and-after snapshots, with rename detection enabled.  If *`path`* is in the "after" commit, and Git finds that it's renamed from some *previous* path in the "before" commit, Git tells you about that, and then starts looking for the *old* path name.

That's essentially all you get.  Your best bet when renaming a file or restructuring a project, then, is to commit *just* the renaming, as one commit, then commit any other changes required.  You do not *have* to do this, as the rename detector can often detect a renamed-*and-changed* file as renamed, but you get a better rename-detection guarantee when you have the rename committed separately, so that each file 100%-matches the previous one.

Note that whether any particular GUI turns on rename-detection, and if so, how, is up to that GUI.  All *Git* provides are the commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>The files inside a commit are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  This means that if you make a thousand commits in a row, and only change `README.md` once, you have, say, 998 shared copies of the old one and 2 shared copies of the new one, or 400 shared copies of the old one and 600 shared copies of the new one, so that either way, it's really only *in* the repository twice, rather than a thousand times.

This also, however, means that the files you see and work on, when you work with a Git repository, *are not in the Git repository*.  The files you see and work with are copies that were *extracted from* the repository, and turned back into usable files in the process.  This explains a lot about why Git behaves the way it does.

<sup>2</sup>Note that the slashes—which go forwards, though you can use backslashes on Windows—are part of each file's name: the name is `old/path/to/name1.py`, for instance.  That's not a folder named `old` containing a folder named `path` and so on, that's just a file whose name is `old/path/to/name1.py`.

<sup>3</sup>From the command line, use `git diff --find-renames` or `git show --find-renames` to enable the rename detector, or set `diff.renames` to `true`.  In Git version 2.9 and later, `diff.renames` is set to `true` by default; in earlier versions, it is set to `false` by default.

Comment: Thank you, torek! Though I haven't understood your answer in detail, I bit the bullet and dived into making changes via Git Bash after backing up the local repo dir. I wound up making the changes with the following set of git commands: (1) git mv -M (expecting this set diff.rename to true); (2) git mv old new (renamed the code file); (3) git commit -am 'commit msg' (made local commits); (4) git push (pushed to remote); (5) git status (confirmed all is clean). Preservation of commits hist on the old code file has been confirmed in remote git repo (online). Thanks again!

Comment: `git mv` doesn't have a `-M`, but that's not important. To set `diff.renames` to `true` (if you're on Git 2.8 or earlier), use `git config`. If your Git version is 2.9 or later, it's already set to `true` by default.

Comment: Thanks, again, torek. It was a typo - I meant setting diff.renames by running `git diff -M`. Does this do the job? I also added `[diff] renames = true` in config just in case. How do I check if diff.renames is set to true (took effect)?

Comment: `git config --get diff.renames` will tell you what it's explicitly set to (for this particular repository). If that doesn't show anything, it's not set and you get the default: `git --version` will tell you which version of Git you're using, and hence what that default is. I like to set mine globally anyway, even though I do not expect to be using a pre-2.9 Git in the future, with `git config --global diff.renames true`.

Comment: The other way to tell is to diff a pair of commits in which some file was renamed, and see if Git reports it as a rename, of course. :-)